# if else statement in elasticsearch

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

We are using elastic search over data of some businesses. Each business has a 'location' and several 'tags' attached to it. We have around 100 tags, tag 1, tag2...tag 100.
Here's the condition : 
businessA : location1 : tag1, tag3, tag55, tag9
businessB : location2 :tag14, tag36,
businessC : location3 :tag11, tag31, tag92, tag55
...similarly business N : location4 : tag33, tag62, tag43, tag1
Now I take 2 inputs from users: 1. Either of "business name" or 'tags' 2. Location

Now there are 3 cases which can come:

1. user searches for 'Business A' in 'location 1'
   Desired result :Business A (since it is present in location 1) shall turn up in result on top
2. user searches for 'Business A' in 'location N'
   Desired result: Although Business A in not in location N but still, due to user's intent it should come on top followed by other businesses of location N
3. User searches for 'tag 3' in 'location 1'
   All the businesses having 'tag3' attached to them and are in location 1 should come on top and then businesses from nearby area.

We are getting absurd results after assigning specific weightage to tags, business and location. If we try to give max. weightage to business name > tag > location, we are able to satisfy statement 1 and 2 and lose statement 3 (due to string match in name). But, if we change the weightage to tag > name > location we get 1 and 3 right but not 2. Can we have all three cases correct with any algorithm ? Is there any way where we can use 'If-Else' statement over elastic search or any such alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

you could use multiquery search and make 2 searches at once: 1. find exact business 2. find related businesses by tags from nearbyarea and merge results in your code